# Exclude package from jacoco code coverage for Android

Tags: android, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, greendao

I'm trying to exclude generated files by GreenDao framework, which placed in a package named dao, from my code coverage report generated by Jacoco, but creating a custom task like following doesn't work.

```
def coverageSourceDirs = [
        '../app/src/main/java'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {

    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R*.class',
                       '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                       '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                       '**/Dao*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.class'
            ])
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/testDebug.exec")
    // Bit hacky but fixes https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174.
    // We iterate through the compiled .class tree and rename $$ to $.
    doFirst {
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        jacoco {
            version = '0.7.3.201502191951'
        }

        testOptions {
            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }

        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.nitralabs.m1_mm"
            minSdkVersion 12
            targetSdkVersion 18
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
            debug {
                testCoverageEnabled = true
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
        compile files('libs/greendao-1.3.1.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
        testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
        testCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.5.2'
    }
```

How can I exclude some classes or package from code coverage without creating custom task?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
classDirectories = fileTree(
        dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
        excludes: ['**/R*.class',
                   '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                   '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                   '**/Dao*.class',
                   '**/*$ViewInjector*.class'
        ])
```

You can put whatever you want to exclude here, in the `excludes` property. It takes an array of strings/regex as you can see that for example InjectAdapter classes are excluded, these classes are generated by dagger I think, and ViewInjector classes are generated by butter knife, so if you suffixed all your GreenDao classes with `Dao` like `somethingDao.class` then you can exclude all classes that end with Dao like so

'**/*Dao.class'

**Explanation**

`**`  Match zero or more directories

`*Dao.class` matches all strings ending with Dao.class

You can get more info on the syntax [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to exclude certain packages, you could include those inside the excludes array as shown below.

```
classDirectories = fileTree(
    dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
    excludes: ['**/R*.class',
               '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
               '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
               '**/Dao*.class',
               '**/*$ViewInjector*.class',
               '**/dao'
    ])
```

The "dao" package exclusion is added in last. You add any package exclusion using same way.